# Getting an empty page with Capybara while testing a Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rails-engines

I am writing tests for a rails engine and I am running into issues when testing with ActiveRecord 3.2.3 where my page has 0 html in it. The same test works fine with ActiveRecord 4.0, 4.1, and 4.2.

The worst part is I'm really not even sure what code to provide in order to help debug this, but here are a few things. Just ask if anything else would he helpful.

**The test file:**

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'spec_helper'
require 'test_app/active_record/seeders/all_seeder'

feature('Search') do
  background do
    AllSeeder.seed
  end

  scenario("pagination") do
    visit('/mountpath/subpath')

    puts "html=#{page.html}" # empty string
    page.save_and_open_page # blank page

    ...
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
app.routes.draw do
  mount MyGem::Engine => "/mountpath"
end
```

The app appears to be spinning up correctly, and if I try to output models in the console they all exist and appear to have been seeded correctly. Any ideas on what I can try to debug this?

**Edit to add more info** - when I say empty page, I mean the html is an empty string. There isn't even an `<html>` tag.

**Editing to add info**

The following code in my test renders fine:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render text: "Hello! #{User.count}"
  end
end
```

But oddly changing it to this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    puts User.all.limit(5).as_json
    render text: "Hello! #{User.count} + #{User.all.limit(5).as_json}"
  end
end
```

results in a 100% empty page. Hopefully that helps a bit.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @Simon nope, I ended up using something else to test. It has been so long I don't recall how I changed it though.